# Кликабельный ScrollView

Tags: android, прокрутка

Как можно реализовать ScrollView, что бы его можно было и скролить, и одновременно с этим по клику на него что-то происходило? Есть ставить клик на него, не работает скролл. Аналогично если делать кнопку прозрачную поверх него.

Comment: а что у вас содержимое в скроле? поставте клик на весь контейнер который внутри скрола

Comment: Внутри будет много TextView, которые, я хочу, чтобы появлялись по клику на экран

Comment: Внутри скролла может быть только один ребенок, вот на него и вешайте слушатель